# Concourse CI: leverage docker image cache

Tags: docker, concourse

I totally understand that Concourse is meant to be stateless, but nevertheless is there any way to re-use already pulled docker images?
In my case, I build ~10 docker images which have the same base image, but each time build is triggered Concourse pulls base image 10 times.

Is it possible to pull that image once and re-use it later (at least in scope of the same build) using standard docker resource?

Yeah, it should be possible to do that using custom image and code it in sh script, but I'm not in fond of inviting bicycles.

If standard docker resource does not allow that, is it possible to extend it somehow to enable such behaviour?

`--cache-from` is not helpful, as CI spends most of time pulling image, not building new layers.

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused as to what the problem is... If you store that base image as a resource, then concourse should cache it and use the cached image to build your new images.

Comment: @JoshZarrabi I don't store it as a resource, as it's referenced only in `Dockerfile's FROM` statement

Answer (score 54):

## Theory

First, some Concourse theory (at least as of v3.3.1):

People often talk about Concourse having a "cache", but misinterpret what that means. Every concourse worker has a set of volumes on disk which are left around, forming a volume cache. This volume cache contains volumes that have been populated by resource `get` and `put` and task `outputs`.

People also often misunderstand how the `docker-image-resource` uses Docker. There is no global docker server running with your Concourse installation, in fact Concourse containers are not Docker containers, they are runC containers. Every `docker-image-resource` process (`check`, `get`, `put`) is run inside of its own runC container, inside of which there is a local docker server running. This means that there's no global docker server that is pulling docker images and caching the layers for further use.

What this implies is that when we talk about caching with the docker-image-resource, it means loading or pre-pulling images into the local docker server.

---

## Practice

Now to the options for optimizing build times:

### `load_base`

#### Background

The `load_base` param in your `docker-image-resource` `put` tells the resource to first `docker load` an image (retrieved via a `get`) into its local docker server, *before* building the image specified via your `put` params.

This is useful when you need to pre-populate an image into your "docker cache." In your case, you would want to preload the image used in the `FROM` directive. This is more efficient because it uses Concourse's own volume caching to only pull the "base" once, making it available to the docker server during the execution of the `FROM` command.

#### Usage

You can use `load_base` as follows:

Suppose you want to build a custom python image, and you have a git repository with a file `ci/Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python python-pip
```

If you wanted to automate building/pushing of this image while taking advantage of **Concourse volume caching** as well as **Docker image layer caching**:

```
resources:
- name: ubuntu
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: ubuntu

- name: python-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: mydocker/python

- name: repo
  type: git
  source:
    uri: ...

jobs:
- name: build-image-from-base
  plan:
  - get: repo
  - get: ubuntu
    params: {save: true}
  - put: python-image
    params:
      load_base: ubuntu
      dockerfile: repo/ci/Dockerfile
```

### `cache` & `cache_tag`

#### Background

The `cache` and `cache_tag` params in your `docker-image-resource` `put` tell the resource to first *pull* a particular image+tag from your remote source, *before* building the image specified via your put params.

This is useful when it's easier to pull down the image than it is to build it from scratch, e.g. you have a very *long* build process, such as expensive compilations

This **DOES NOT** utilize Concourse's volume caching, and utilizes Docker's `--cache-from` feature (which runs the risk of needing to first perform a `docker pull`) during every `put`.

#### Usage

You can use `cache` and `cache_tag` as follows:

Suppose you want to build a custom ruby image, where you compile ruby from source, and you have a git repository with a file `ci/Dockerfile` as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Install Ruby
RUN mkdir /tmp/ruby;\
  cd /tmp/ruby;\
  curl ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz | tar xz;\
  cd ruby-2.0.0-p247;\
  chmod +x configure;\
  ./configure --disable-install-rdoc;\
  make;\
  make install;\
  gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc

RUN gem install nokogiri
```

If you wanted to automate building/pushing of this image while taking advantage of only **Docker image layer caching**:

```
resources: 
- name: compiled-ruby-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: mydocker/ruby
    tag: 2.0.0-compiled

- name: repo
  type: git
  source:
    uri: ...

jobs:
- name: build-image-from-cache
  plan:
  - get: repo
  - put: compiled-ruby-image
    params:
      dockerfile: repo/ci/Dockerfile
      cache: mydocker/ruby
      cache_tag: 2.0.0-compiled
```

---

## Recommendation

If you want to increase efficiency of building docker images, my personal belief is that `load_base` should be used in most cases. Because it uses a resource `get`, it takes advantage of Concourse volume caching, and avoids needing to do extra `docker pull`s.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, unfortunately I won't be able to check it out in an upcoming weeks.

Comment: Tested, works well. Avoids the [`file not found` error](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1457#issuecomment-358491394) when using `skip_download` if the image does not already exist on the worker. Requires that `params: {save:true}` be set on the `get` for the input Docker image resource.

Comment: This is a super useful answer. Could you also update it with how `cache_from` is related to `load_base` and `cache`?  It looks like `cache_from` has a similar effect as `cache` in that it translates to `docker build --cache-from` but it's specifically supposed to pull from the local cache volume instead of over the network. So `cache_from` is for caching build steps and `load_base` is for caching pull layers. So I'd imagine most people will want to do both, but then do the base image layers get pulled twice?

Comment: I edited to add `save: true`, as the pipeline failed otherwise, with `open ubuntu/image: no such file or directory`.

Comment: This concourse resource is old, confusing, and crufty. Note the current work to rewrite/re-engineer this: https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource/issues/190

Comment: this is easily the most useful information i've encountered for building docker images with concourse. thank you!

Comment: First of all, thanks for this, it is amazing and very useful! I have a question and an observation.

**Question**: Can't you combine `load_base` to avoid re-pulling the base image AND `cache_from` to take advantage of Docker's layers cache? (I'm going to try that as it could both help with avoid unnecessary downloads and reducing build time if cached layers can be used)

**Observation**: It may be good to add a note that the `ubuntu` in the `load_base` it's the name of the `get` task, not the name of the base image (or at least that's my understanding)

Thanks again ❤️

Comment: oh ... if there _just_ would be a way to use host docker instead of `runC`  ...